# Adafruit SSD1306, I2C, ATmega1284p: OLED Display askew/misaligned

Tags: arduino, atmega, i2c, oled

Another strange problem here. The setup:

Adafruit SSD1306 OLED board connected to an ATMega1284p via I2C.

Since I "upped" my 1284 to 8MHz (which I needed to to reliably talk to my temperature sensors via OneWire) the display is "akew" or "misaligned" (see below) in a way that the "zero coordinate" (what I'd call the beginning of the screen) is not at the very top any more but rather about a quarter screen down (approximately at the red line):
[image: red line depicts the approx beginning of the screen, should be at the very top]

I loaded the unaltered example sketch for the SSD1306 from Adafruit which works fine at 1MHz on the 1284 or at 16MHz using the Duemilanove board.

Any ideas what could cause the screen to be "moved downwards" in such a way?

Thank you!

The code (unaltered example sketch, only the reset pin is moved to pin 21 (this works fine at 1MHz), ie. the `#define OLED_RESET 21`-line is usually `#define OLED_RESET 4`):

```
/*********************************************************************
This is an example for our Monochrome OLEDs based on SSD1306 drivers

  Pick one up today in the adafruit shop!
  ------> http://www.adafruit.com/category/63_98

This example is for a 128x64 size display using I2C to communicate
3 pins are required to interface (2 I2C and one reset)

Adafruit invests time and resources providing this open source code, 
please support Adafruit and open-source hardware by purchasing 
products from Adafruit!

Written by Limor Fried/Ladyada  for Adafruit Industries.  
BSD license, check license.txt for more information
All text above, and the splash screen must be included in any redistribution
*********************************************************************/

#include <Wire.h>
#include <Adafruit_GFX.h>
#include <Adafruit_SSD1306.h>

#define OLED_RESET 21
Adafruit_SSD1306 display(OLED_RESET);

#define NUMFLAKES 10
#define XPOS 0
#define YPOS 1
#define DELTAY 2


#define LOGO16_GLCD_HEIGHT 16 
#define LOGO16_GLCD_WIDTH  16 
static unsigned char PROGMEM logo16_glcd_bmp[] =
{ B00000000, B11000000,
  B00000001, B11000000,
  B00000001, B11000000,
  B00000011, B11100000,
  B11110011, B11100000,
  B11111110, B11111000,
  B01111110, B11111111,
  B00110011, B10011111,
  B00011111, B11111100,
  B00001101, B01110000,
  B00011011, B10100000,
  B00111111, B11100000,
  B00111111, B11110000,
  B01111100, B11110000,
  B01110000, B01110000,
  B00000000, B00110000 };

#if (SSD1306_LCDHEIGHT != 64)
#error("Height incorrect, please fix Adafruit_SSD1306.h!");
#endif

void setup()   {                
  Serial.begin(9600);

  // by default, we'll generate the high voltage from the 3.3v line internally! (neat!)
  display.begin(SSD1306_SWITCHCAPVCC, 0x3D);  // initialize with the I2C addr 0x3D (for the 128x64)
  // init done

  display.display(); // show splashscreen
  delay(2000);
  display.clearDisplay();   // clears the screen and buffer

  // draw a single pixel
  display.drawPixel(10, 10, WHITE);
  display.display();
  delay(2000);
  display.clearDisplay();

  // draw many lines
  testdrawline();
  display.display();
  delay(2000);
  display.clearDisplay();

  // draw rectangles
  testdrawrect();
  display.display();
  delay(2000);
  display.clearDisplay();

  // draw multiple rectangles
  testfillrect();
  display.display();
  delay(2000);
  display.clearDisplay();

  // draw mulitple circles
  testdrawcircle();
  display.display();
  delay(2000);
  display.clearDisplay();

  // draw a white circle, 10 pixel radius
  display.fillCircle(display.width()/2, display.height()/2, 10, WHITE);
  display.display();
  delay(2000);
  display.clearDisplay();

  testdrawroundrect();
  delay(2000);
  display.clearDisplay();

  testfillroundrect();
  delay(2000);
  display.clearDisplay();

  testdrawtriangle();
  delay(2000);
  display.clearDisplay();

  testfilltriangle();
  delay(2000);
  display.clearDisplay();

  // draw the first ~12 characters in the font
  testdrawchar();
  display.display();
  delay(2000);
  display.clearDisplay();

  // draw scrolling text
  testscrolltext();
  delay(2000);
  display.clearDisplay();

  // text display tests
  display.setTextSize(1);
  display.setTextColor(WHITE);
  display.setCursor(0,0);
  display.println("Hello, world!");
  display.setTextColor(BLACK, WHITE); // 'inverted' text
  display.println(3.141592);
  display.setTextSize(2);
  display.setTextColor(WHITE);
  display.print("0x"); display.println(0xDEADBEEF, HEX);
  display.display();
  delay(2000);

  // miniature bitmap display
  display.clearDisplay();
  display.drawBitmap(30, 16,  logo16_glcd_bmp, 16, 16, 1);
  display.display();

  // invert the display
  display.invertDisplay(true);
  delay(1000); 
  display.invertDisplay(false);
  delay(1000); 

  // draw a bitmap icon and 'animate' movement
  testdrawbitmap(logo16_glcd_bmp, LOGO16_GLCD_HEIGHT, LOGO16_GLCD_WIDTH);
}


void loop() {

}


void testdrawbitmap(const uint8_t *bitmap, uint8_t w, uint8_t h) {
  uint8_t icons[NUMFLAKES][3];
  srandom(666);     // whatever seed

  // initialize
  for (uint8_t f=0; f< NUMFLAKES; f++) {
    icons[f][XPOS] = random() % display.width();
    icons[f][YPOS] = 0;
    icons[f][DELTAY] = random() % 5 + 1;

    Serial.print("x: ");
    Serial.print(icons[f][XPOS], DEC);
    Serial.print(" y: ");
    Serial.print(icons[f][YPOS], DEC);
    Serial.print(" dy: ");
    Serial.println(icons[f][DELTAY], DEC);
  }

  while (1) {
    // draw each icon
    for (uint8_t f=0; f< NUMFLAKES; f++) {
      display.drawBitmap(icons[f][XPOS], icons[f][YPOS], logo16_glcd_bmp, w, h, WHITE);
    }
    display.display();
    delay(200);

    // then erase it + move it
    for (uint8_t f=0; f< NUMFLAKES; f++) {
      display.drawBitmap(icons[f][XPOS], icons[f][YPOS],  logo16_glcd_bmp, w, h, BLACK);
      // move it
      icons[f][YPOS] += icons[f][DELTAY];
      // if its gone, reinit
      if (icons[f][YPOS] > display.height()) {
    icons[f][XPOS] = random() % display.width();
    icons[f][YPOS] = 0;
    icons[f][DELTAY] = random() % 5 + 1;
      }
    }
   }
}


void testdrawchar(void) {
  display.setTextSize(1);
  display.setTextColor(WHITE);
  display.setCursor(0,0);

  for (uint8_t i=0; i < 168; i++) {
    if (i == '\n') continue;
    display.write(i);
    if ((i > 0) && (i % 21 == 0))
      display.println();
  }    
  display.display();
}

void testdrawcircle(void) {
  for (int16_t i=0; i<display.height(); i+=2) {
    display.drawCircle(display.width()/2, display.height()/2, i, WHITE);
    display.display();
  }
}

void testfillrect(void) {
  uint8_t color = 1;
  for (int16_t i=0; i<display.height()/2; i+=3) {
    // alternate colors
    display.fillRect(i, i, display.width()-i*2, display.height()-i*2, color%2);
    display.display();
    color++;
  }
}

void testdrawtriangle(void) {
  for (int16_t i=0; i<min(display.width(),display.height())/2; i+=5) {
    display.drawTriangle(display.width()/2, display.height()/2-i,
                     display.width()/2-i, display.height()/2+i,
                     display.width()/2+i, display.height()/2+i, WHITE);
    display.display();
  }
}

void testfilltriangle(void) {
  uint8_t color = WHITE;
  for (int16_t i=min(display.width(),display.height())/2; i>0; i-=5) {
    display.fillTriangle(display.width()/2, display.height()/2-i,
                     display.width()/2-i, display.height()/2+i,
                     display.width()/2+i, display.height()/2+i, WHITE);
    if (color == WHITE) color = BLACK;
    else color = WHITE;
    display.display();
  }
}

void testdrawroundrect(void) {
  for (int16_t i=0; i<display.height()/2-2; i+=2) {
    display.drawRoundRect(i, i, display.width()-2*i, display.height()-2*i, display.height()/4, WHITE);
    display.display();
  }
}

void testfillroundrect(void) {
  uint8_t color = WHITE;
  for (int16_t i=0; i<display.height()/2-2; i+=2) {
    display.fillRoundRect(i, i, display.width()-2*i, display.height()-2*i, display.height()/4, color);
    if (color == WHITE) color = BLACK;
    else color = WHITE;
    display.display();
  }
}

void testdrawrect(void) {
  for (int16_t i=0; i<display.height()/2; i+=2) {
    display.drawRect(i, i, display.width()-2*i, display.height()-2*i, WHITE);
    display.display();
  }
}

void testdrawline() {  
  for (int16_t i=0; i<display.width(); i+=4) {
    display.drawLine(0, 0, i, display.height()-1, WHITE);
    display.display();
  }
  for (int16_t i=0; i<display.height(); i+=4) {
    display.drawLine(0, 0, display.width()-1, i, WHITE);
    display.display();
  }
  delay(250);

  display.clearDisplay();
  for (int16_t i=0; i<display.width(); i+=4) {
    display.drawLine(0, display.height()-1, i, 0, WHITE);
    display.display();
  }
  for (int16_t i=display.height()-1; i>=0; i-=4) {
    display.drawLine(0, display.height()-1, display.width()-1, i, WHITE);
    display.display();
  }
  delay(250);

  display.clearDisplay();
  for (int16_t i=display.width()-1; i>=0; i-=4) {
    display.drawLine(display.width()-1, display.height()-1, i, 0, WHITE);
    display.display();
  }
  for (int16_t i=display.height()-1; i>=0; i-=4) {
    display.drawLine(display.width()-1, display.height()-1, 0, i, WHITE);
    display.display();
  }
  delay(250);

  display.clearDisplay();
  for (int16_t i=0; i<display.height(); i+=4) {
    display.drawLine(display.width()-1, 0, 0, i, WHITE);
    display.display();
  }
  for (int16_t i=0; i<display.width(); i+=4) {
    display.drawLine(display.width()-1, 0, i, display.height()-1, WHITE); 
    display.display();
  }
  delay(250);
}

void testscrolltext(void) {
  display.setTextSize(2);
  display.setTextColor(WHITE);
  display.setCursor(10,0);
  display.clearDisplay();
  display.println("scroll");
  display.display();

  display.startscrollright(0x00, 0x0F);
  delay(2000);
  display.stopscroll();
  delay(1000);
  display.startscrollleft(0x00, 0x0F);
  delay(2000);
  display.stopscroll();
  delay(1000);    
  display.startscrolldiagright(0x00, 0x07);
  delay(2000);
  display.startscrolldiagleft(0x00, 0x07);
  delay(2000);
  display.stopscroll();
}
```

Comment: Christian, please try to minimize the code to the absolute minimum to reproduce the problem. With long listings fewer people will look in depth.

Comment: Did you set the hardware definition for your board so the arduino libraries are using the right ticks/second?

Comment: Did you ever find a solution to this problem? I'm getting the same thing myself. Cheers!!

Comment: Apparently your alter ego figured it out! ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Update: I've now fixed the problem I was having with this - the problem in my case was caused because the page start and end address wasn't being set during initialisation. I've added the following command to the begin() function and now my displays are always correctly initialised.

```
// I was hitting a problem where the start line was not going back to zero during reset
// Setting the page start and end addresses seems to fix that.
command( 0x22 ); // Set page start and end addresses
command( 0x00 ); // start at zero
command (0x07) ; // end at seven.
```

Hope that helps someone out there... Took me forever to work it out.

Cheers!!

Comment: Thank you for commenting and thus adding to the big brain of internet knowledge!